# mvc class reference count doesn't include views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

Hello all I am using visual studio 2013 for asp.net MVC5 c#.

I am kinda baffled the references made from the views (in example @model NSpace.Models.***xxxviewmodel***) aren't getting counted above the class codes. And this affects the renaming also.

I tried [this](http://blog.falafel.com/get-compile-time-view-errors-in-asp-net-mvc/) (`<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>`) but still doesnt see in the reference list.

I'm hoping I am missing a setting for this and its not by design.

Any way to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setting that I know of, for this.

The reason you are not able to see the count for the references that are sitting in the view, is for the simple reason that Views do not get compiled, they are actually just HTML pages.

Also, renaming will not work for objects sitting in the view.

Fortunately, C# is a statically typed language. What this means is, the C# compiler does static type checking at compile time, so you will get an Error List before the application will be able to build and compile.